# How to control multiple sprite kit nodes with the same name?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Swift 2
SpriteKit

So I'm using the following code to spawn enemies randomly and then to move them towards the player. But for some reason, only the first enemy moves towards the player, the rest do nothing. I'm new to this so all details would help.

Under didmovetoview:

```
        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(3, withRange: 2)
        let spawn = SKAction.runBlock {
            let Enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy.png")
            Enemy.size.height = (70) //138
            Enemy.size.width = (49) //99
            Enemy.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) - 100 , CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) - 100)
            Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (rectangleOfSize: Enemy.size)
            Enemy.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
            Enemy.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
            Enemy.physicsBody!.friction = 0
            Enemy.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
            Enemy.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 1
            Enemy.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 1
            Enemy.name = "Enemy"
            Enemy.zPosition = 3
            self.addChild(Enemy)
            self.EnemyExists=true

        }
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
        self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))
```

Under update func:

```
            let Enemy = childNodeWithName("Enemy") as! SKSpriteNode
            let Player = childNodeWithName("Player") as! SKSpriteNode

            if EnemySpeed == OriginalEnemySpeed {

                let impulseVector = CGVector(dx: (Player.position.x - Enemy.position.x)/200, dy: (Player.position.y - Enemy.position.y)/200)
                Enemy.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulseVector)
            }

            if Enemy.position.x + Enemy.size.width / 4 > size.width {
                Enemy.position.x = Enemy.size.width / 4

            }
            else if Enemy.position.x + Enemy.size.width / 4 < 0 {
                Enemy.position.x = size.width - Enemy.size.width / 4

            }

            if Enemy.position.y + Enemy.size.height / 4 > size.height {
                Enemy.position.y = Enemy.size.height / 4

            }
            else if Enemy.position.y + Enemy.size.height / 4 < 0 {
                Enemy.position.y = size.height - Enemy.size.height / 4

            }

            EnemySpeed-=1
            if EnemySpeed < 1 {
                EnemySpeed = OriginalEnemySpeed
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`childNodeWithName("Enemy")` will only pick up the first sprite in the scene called `Enemy`.

You need to loop over **all** sprites called enemy with `enumerateChildNodesWithName`:

```
        enumerateChildNodesWithName("Enemy") {
            node, stop in
            let Enemy = node as! SKSpriteNode

            // Your enemy movement/update code here

        }
```

You'll have to do something about your `EnemySpeed` variable if it's supposed to refer to the speed of the sprite you are currently processing, as it's just a single instance variable and not a property of that sprite. You'll probably want to use Enemy.physicsBody.velocity, which is a CGVector, so to convert this to a speed you need:

```
enemySpeedX = enemy.physicsbody.velocity.dx
enemySpeedY = enemy.physicsbody.velocity.dy
enemySpeed = sqrt(enemySpeedX* enemySpeedX + enemySpeedY* enemySpeedY)
```

Also check your naming standards; most things should be camel-case so `Enemy` should be `enemy`, `OriginalEnemySpeed` should be  `originalEnemySpeed` etc.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to modify my enemySpeed to become a CGVector? I only want the enemies to chase the player, preferably at a constant speed instead of the current situation where they become faster as the player is further.